# SharePoint 2010 list workflow with form action button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list, custom-form

I have an edit item form on a list in SharePoint Designer 2010 and I want to run a specific list workflow (not site workflow) when clicked this button. How can I do this? If this is not possible, how can I set the value of a list item when form action button clicked? I have a workflow which is using a column value in if statements. If I set the value of that column when button clicked, I can use this workflow when list item updated.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when clicked this button" which button are you referring to?

Comment: I'm using a form action button with "Commit" action. Added screen shot.

Comment: You're attaching the standard commit action to a custom button then. In this case, just attach a workflow to your list and set it to start automatically whenever an item is edited

Comment: I did this. But I'm using a column value as a parameter in this workflow. Like, if flag=1 then send email to all users, if flag=2 then send email to only current user. I want to set this "flag" value only if this button clicked.

Comment: This is still unclear to me. If this is the only commit button present in the edit form, then it will always be clicked (unless the user clicks on cancel). Meaning that the flag can be set to a constant value. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, I have a few forms and only one workflow and I am deciding to send e-mail in this workflow using this flag value. I want to realize that which edit from changed the item and ran workflow. So, I want to set flag=107 in this edit form and I will set flag=108 in another edit form which uses same workflow. Also, I can not set flag value using query string parameter because it is waiting to changed via form from user manually.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have a FLAG column in your list and that you have multiple edit forms and you are looking for a way to discern which edit form actually caused the editing.

You can achieve your goal by adding a `<asp:HiddenField>` to each edit form, and setting its Value to the value you want the flag to have.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hidFlag" Value="108" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','hidFlag','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Flag')}"/>
```

Pay attention to the ddwrt:DataBind syntax. For more information about its usage, see [this blog post](http://www.bryancook.net/2009/09/understanding-sharepoints-ddwrtdatabind.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I solved my problem passing ListItemId parameter through a site workflow. If there is any problem, I will try this and write comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [Custom action] in your picture above. What this will do is create a workflow associated with your form.

If there are any fields on your form formatted as "Label," then you can use those form fields in the workflow. There, you should be able to set a value for your list item. You'll have to have some way of locating it.